# Get associated record for each object in ActiveRecord array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a collection of `Posts`, where an `Organization` has many posts. A post belongs to an `Account`. The models look like the following:

```rb
# Post class
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account, foreign_key: 'account_id'
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true

  validates :content, length: { in: 1..500 }
end

# Organization
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end
```

I can get the posts of an organization (ie in the console, I can do `Organization.first.posts`, which returns a shape like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 101,
        "accountId": 50,
        "postableType": "Organization",
        "postableId": 3,
        "content": "Consequatur in illum vel voluptates.",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.271Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.271Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "accountId": 46,
        "postableType": "Organization",
        "postableId": 3,
        "content": "Fugit totam minus et consequatur.",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.274Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.274Z"
    },
]
```

With that query, what would be the best way of including the `Account` object with every `Post` returned? I tried doing something like: `Organization.first.posts.includes(:account)` and `Organization.first.posts.joins(:account)` but that just returned the same thing. Would it be by simply mapping over and doing a separate query to find the account, and merging that `Account` object with the `Post`?

For example, I'd ideally like to return something like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 101,
        "account": {
            "id": 46,
            "firstName": "Bob"
        },
        "postableType": "Organization",
        "postableId": 3,
        "content": "Consequatur in illum vel voluptates.",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.271Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.271Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "account": {
            "id": 46,
            "firstName": "Bob"
        },
        "postableType": "Organization",
        "postableId": 3,
        "content": "Fugit totam minus et consequatur.",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.274Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-23T04:57:45.274Z"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by doing:

```
Organization.first.posts.as_json(include: :account)
```

I'm not sure if there is a better ActiveRecord-y way of doing this, but it worked for my use-case above.